# Javascript - google map, simple reverse geocoding - always zero results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a simple google map with drag event and with address lookup.
On the drag event, I want to update the lat / lon input fields (working ) but also the address ( not working ),.

I might be too tired , and probably just missing some tiny obvious thingy here , but I just can not seem to get it to work ( always return zero results ) ..

See in action : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/Ss4tp/

JS code :

```
    // <![CDATA[
var map;
var markersArray = []; // to be used later to clear overlay array
var marker;
var address;


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var lat = parseFloat(jQuery('#LatTxt').val());
    var lon = parseFloat(jQuery('#LonTxt').val());

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(jQuery('[id^=k99_geolocation_]')[0], myOptions);
    placeMarker(myLatlng);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    // Find Adress and set zoom when found

    jQuery('#k99_geo_address').click(function() { codeAddress() });
    function codeAddress() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  map.setZoom(11); // how to do that according to the level ?? (country ,city, street, house ??)

                 if (marker) {
                    marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                }
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
           }
   );
}

    //Function to extract longitude



    function placeMarker(location) {
        if (marker) {
            marker.setPosition(location);
        } else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'Drag me',
                map: map
            });
            markersArray.push(marker); // to be used later to clear overlay array
        }
    }
// adding drag event
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) { updatelonlat(); });

    // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array

    function clearOverlays() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (var i = 0, length = markersArray.length; i < length; i++) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
    }
    //Jquery update HTML input boxes

    function updatelonlat() {
        jQuery('#LatTxt').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
        jQuery('#LonTxt').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            jQuery('#address').val(results[1].formatted_address);

              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
           } );
    }


    // add event click
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
        //document.getElementById("#LatTxt").value = event.latLng.lat();
        //down lan lon values  from http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/
        updatelonlat();
    });

}); 
    // ]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In updatelonlat you must use `{latLng:marker.getPosition()}` as argument for `geocoder.geocode()`

Comment: Right . I had it there , and removed it in one of the iterations . Thanks !!